# Automatic co-author when squashing in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When squashing multiple commits from different devs into one, it would be really great, if IntelliJ would add the `Co-authored-by` tag a the end for each author. Is this somehow possible?
I know github can do this when squashing.

If this is not possible by IntelliJ/Git plugin, is there way to do this as automatic as possible?

Answer (score 0):

There was a request for this:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186425/Provide-a-way-to-include-Co-Authored-By-in-commits-easily

And a feature of `Co-author` has been added to Commit meessage:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293998/Complete-Co-authored-by-and-user-nameemail-completion-in-co-authored-commits